# Active Admin and Stripe Membership Plans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, stripe-payments

I'm trying to Add membership plans in stripe using active admin.
I was able to add it during creation of column. But now i want to edit the created subscription.
Here is my active admin page.. How should the controller for update and destroy be?

```
ActiveAdmin.register SubscriptionPlan do
  menu  priority: 10
  permit_params :name, :amount, :interval

  index do
    selectable_column
    default_actions
    column :name
    column :amount
    column :interval
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Subscription Plan" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :amount
      f.input :interval, as: :select, collection: ["week","month","year"]
    end
    f.actions
  end


  controller do
    def create
      create! do |format|
       Stripe::Plan.create(
        :amount =>  params[:subscription_plan][:amount].to_i,
        :interval =>  params[:subscription_plan][:interval],
        :name =>  params[:subscription_plan][:name],
        :currency => 'usd',
        :id =>  params[:subscription_plan][:name]
      )      
      end
    end
    def update
      update! do |format|

      end
    end
    def destroy
      destroy! do |format|

      end
    end
  end 

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea i myself found a solution for this..
on edit i got its value by passing the created id of stripe plan and with it i edited the Json and saved it.